# Magento layered navigation filter out configurable product out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, layered-navigation

I have configurable products with size variations, for example small, medium and large.

In product X, the simple product for the small size is out of stock.

If I set in the layered navigation to filter by small size, this product X still shows in my product list, but when I navigate into product page, the size is not available.

I am looking for a way to filter out product X if I choose to filter for the size small.

I have looked at all the questions on Magento stackexchange suggested, but none of them seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Try reindex all.
If it does not help, can you get sql query for collection with filter and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

set the "Display Out of Stock Products" to no